# Unnest hits.product.customDimensions Error

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm having issues querying the `hits.product.customDimensions` (same logic works correclty on the `hits.customDimensions`).  I can not understand why the additional nest would cause an array error.  Any help appreciated.  Thank you!

**Standard SQL**

```
SELECT
  fullVisitorId,
  visitId,
  hits.hitNumber,
  product.productSKU,
  MAX(IF(c.index=1,c.value, null)) AS customDimesion1
FROM 17823880.ga_sessions_20180128,
UNNEST(hits) AS hits, 
UNNEST(hits.product) as product,
UNNEST(hits.product.customDimensions) as c
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
```

**Error**:

> Cannot access field customDimensions on a value with type
>   ARRAY> at [11:23]

**Standard SQL - This query works with no error below**

```
SELECT
  fullVisitorId,
  visitId,
  hits.hitNumber,
  MAX(IF(c.index=1,c.value, null)) AS customDimesion1
FROM 17823880.ga_sessions_20180128,
UNNEST(hits) AS hits,
UNNEST(hits.customDimensions) as c
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: You actually don't need to cross join product.customDimensions, you can just use a sub-select: `(SELECT value FROM product.customDimensions WHERE index=1) AS cd1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you gave an alias of `product` to the elements coming out of `UNNEST(hits.product)`, but you didn't refer to that alias in the subsequent `UNNEST(hits.product.customDimensions)`, so you ended up with the original `product` array instead of its element after unnesting. Try this instead:

```
SELECT
fullVisitorId,
visitId,
hits.hitNumber,
product.productSKU,
MAX(IF(c.index=1,c.value, null)) AS customDimesion1
FROM 17823880.ga_sessions_20180128,
UNNEST(hits) AS hits, 
UNNEST(hits.product) as product,
UNNEST(product.customDimensions) as c
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Comment: Yes thank you!  I knew I was missing something simple in there. It was making me crazy.